# custom validator not working in bootsrap

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a text field and if it will be empty then I want to throw an error. I am using a JavaScript function and a custom validator for this.

```
<div class="table-container" style="border: none">
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-col">
            <div class="label">
                Abstract Title (*)
            </div>
            <div class="smallnormal">
                Please enter the abstract title EXACTLY as it will appear on the poster
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="table-row">
       <div class="table-col">
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" MaxLength="500" CssClass="textEntry" Width="800px"></asp:TextBox>
           <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator6" ClientValidationFunction = "checkTitle" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Title required" CssClass="failureNotification">[ * ]</asp:CustomValidator>
       </div>
   </div>

<script>
    function checkTitle(sender, args) {
        var isValid = false;
        var bodyWithoutHtmlTag = document.getElementById('<%=txtTitle.ClientID%>').value;
        var wordCountInBody = wordCount(bodyWithoutHtmlTag);

        if ((wordCountInBody - 1) == 0) {
            var singleWordInBody = bodyWithoutHtmlTag;
            singleWordInBody = singleWordInBody.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi, "");
            var lengthOfWord = singleWordInBody.length;

            if (lengthOfWord >= 1) {
                args.IsValid = true;
            }
            else {
                alert("arg is false");
                args.IsValid = false;
            }
        }             
    }
</script>
```

It was working fine when I was not using bootstrap properties, but when I applied bootstrap properties it stopped working.

After bootstrap:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="form-group form-group-md">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label>Abstract Title (*)</label>
                    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator6" ClientValidationFunction = "checkTitle" 
                                        runat="server" ErrorMessage="Title required" CssClass="failureNotification">[ * ]</asp:CustomValidator>
                    <small>Please enter the abstract title EXACTLY as it will appear on the poster</small>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" MaxLength="500" CssClass="form-control" Width=""></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi. What version of the .NET Framework are you using? If you're using 4.5+, the custom validator may use jQuery 2 internally, which may cause a problem with Bootstrap as it comes with jQuery 1 and there may be a conflict occurring.

Comment: I am using .NET Framework 4.0